# Why does not the method enter in the custom exception?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities

I am trying to catch an exception where the email is entered twice and it has to catch the exception as the email is unique. I have the following code to catch the exception:

Custom Exception class:

```
public class EmailAlreadyExistsException : Exception
{
    public EmailAlreadyExistsException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
```

Where the exception is supposed to be catched:

```
public void UpdateUser(Customer customer)
{
    try
    {
        this.Entities.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (CommonLayer.exceptions.EmailAlreadyExistsException ex)
    {
       throw ex;
    }              
}
```

Comment: I would not try to catch an exception at `SaveChanges` because it can get messy to find exactly this error in the depply nested EF/SqlServer exception tree. I would query for the entered email address in the database before trying to submit.

Comment: Based on what you wrote to my answer below "the exception is sqlexception i need to extend the custom excception class from sqlexception.. –"  this question post isnt asking the same question.  If you want to know how to extend exceptions then you should be asking that.  Clearly in this question all you are asking is why isnt my partially provided code not working.

Answer (score 0):

Good night, exception raised not a custom exception(EmailAlreadyExistsException) so your catch (CommonLayer.exceptions.EmailAlreadyExistsException ex) not cached and continue, try this:

```
public void UpdateUser(Customer customer)
{
    try
    {
        this.Entities.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if(ex.Message.Contains("EmailAlreadyExistsConstraint"))//custom if
            throw new CommonLayer.exceptions.EmailAlreadyExistsException(ex.Message);
        else
            throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would transform *every* exception into the `EmailAlreadyExistsException`. Thats probably not the right approach.

Comment: Yes, Must be added a if statement.

Comment: the exception is sqlexception i need to extend the custom excception class from sqlexception.

Comment: you must get message from inner exceptions, if error raised from custom constraint(trigger,unique column,constraints), it's have a name and you can get it from inner exception message with like : Message.Contains("IXEmailUniquekey")